# Good way to organize all sub classes into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a base class and several subclasses. Each sub class has an attribute called "regex" containing a string:

```
# module level dictionary
action_types = {}

class Action():
    regex = '.*'

    @classmethod
    def register_action(cls):
        action_types[cls.regex] = cls


class Sing(Action):
    regex = r'^SING [0-9]+'
    Sing.register_action()

class Dance(Action):
    regex = r'^DANCE [0-9]+'
    Dance.register_action()
```

I want to register all the sub classes in the action_types dictionary using each classes' regex as a key. I want the logic to register the class to be confined to the base class.

The above example doesn't work, and I believe this is because the Dance and Sing variables are not yet available in the namespace when they are used.

Is there any way to register the sub classes in the dictionary during the class initialization?

Comment: Why are you using separate classes for this? What's wrong with making the regex an instance member, and Sing, Dance etc. instances?

Comment: In practice, I want  Sing and Dance classes to have unique __init__ functions. I think using a meta-class pattern like in the example provided by Ignacio actually provides the best of both worlds - sub classes are instances, but can also have unique init functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how you want to do it.

```
class ActionRegistry(type):
  registry = {}
  def __init__(cls, name, bases, dic):
    if 'regex' in dic:
      cls.registry[dic['regex']] = cls
    super(ActionRegistry, cls).__init__(name, bases, dic)

class Action(object):
  __metaclass__ = ActionRegistry

class Sing(Action):
  regex = r'^SING [0-9]+'

class Dance(Action):
  regex = r'^DANCE [0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
action_types = {}

class Action():
    regex = '.*'

    @classmethod
    def register_action(cls):
        action_types[cls.regex] = cls


class Sing(Action):
    regex = r'^SING [0-9]+'
Sing.register_action()

class Dance(Action):
    regex = r'^DANCE [0-9]+'
Dance.register_action()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do it during class initialization.

Here's a simpler way to do it:

```
action_types = {}

class Action():
    regex = '.*'

class Sing(Action):
    regex = r'^SING [0-9]+'

class Dance(Action):
    regex = r'^DANCE [0-9]+'

def register_action(cls):
    action_types[cls.regex] = cls

for cls in (Sing, Dance):
    register_action(cls)
```